# Create local respository using git same as remote respository (Local git server same as remote)

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash

I am new to GIT
I have a remote git repository. I want to create a local repository which is same as remote (with all branches and tags same as remote).
I want to test my git commands on my local repository then I can push that to remote .
Many post I had seen where people are telling to do clone or mirror but that is not working for me .

`local rep       <---> remote rep
-> all branches  <===> -> all branches
-> all tags      <===> -> all tags`

Now I want to use my local repository as server

`git clone "D:\localrep\"` should have all the features (branch, tags & history) as remote server

Comment: why is `git clone` not working??

Comment: @J.Baoby.  1. I cloned to D:\project (it has become git repo). 2. When I try to clone from "D:\project" I am not getting the branches which I can see in remote . Please revert me if not understood my scenario

Comment: When I clone again from my local repo to local I want to see all the branches and tags same as remote server

Comment: So in your D:\project you don't see your remote branches when you do `git branch -a`??

Comment: I can see in D:\project. But If I do clone again from 'D:\project' then I cannot see. That is I want to use 'D:\project' as server now not remote location

Comment: Yes git clone won't create all branches locally for you but git knows that the remote has multiple branches and you can (and must) create them locally by yourself

Comment: I have a lot of branches in remote . I cannot create every history . I want to simulate same environment as remote in my local. Please let me know how can I do it . Thanks in advance @J.Baoby

Comment: See the answer!

Comment: I added a command to create branches as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already told you in the comments, `git clone` won't (as far as I know) automatically create all branches locally for you.
You can check all branches you have in your local repository with `git branch`.

```
$ git branch
* master
```

Here this git repository has only one branch: the master branch. It will look like that if you clone it with `git clone`.
If you want to check which remote branches your local repository is aware of they exist you can have to run `git branch -a`. The remote branches will be of this form:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/other_branch
  remotes/origin/branch_two
```

The ones with "remotes/" are the branches in the remote repository. So here you see that the remote repository `origin` possesses 3 branches (the lines with `remotes/origin/<branch_name>`) : master, other_branch and branch_two.
If you want them locally as well you have to create them, with `git checkout -b` for example:

```
git checkout -b <new_local_branch> <remote_repository>/<remote_branch_name>
```

You replace `<new_local_branch>` with the name you want it to have in your local repository and `<remote_repository>/<remote_branch_name>` with what comes after `remotes/` in the output of `git branch -a`.
For example to create the branch `other_branch` localy as a copy of the remote branch with the same name you just do:

```
git checkout -b other_branch origin/other_branch
```

then you'll see the output of `git branch` will be

```
$ git branch
 master
* other_branch
```

If you want to do it automatically you can create a command based on the output of `git branch -a` like this one:

```
git branch -a | grep "remotes/origin" | egrep -v "origin/(master|HEAD)$" | \
   sed "s:remotes/\([^/]\+/\(.\+\)\)$:git checkout -b \2 \1:" | bash
```

This one will create all branches locally except the master-branch. If there are other branches it doesn't have to create add them in the regex of egrep between the "()", separated with a "|"

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I was expecting. May be my question was not clear . I don't know why people had given negative points to it .

Comment: It's my pleasure! Yes it can be your question wasn't clear enough! Some people may be particularly rigorous and severe